# How many concurrent SSH client connections are possible from one machine to different servers

Tags: linux, ssh, remote, tcp, openssh

I wanted to understand how many concurrent ssh client connections are possible from one machine to n different ssh servers. Assuming n is a pretty large number e.g 100k.

Also want to understand what are the best practices regarding this as to how many connections should I ideally open at a time given say if I have a 16GB RAM and 2.8GHz i7. Is there a best practice one needs to follow

Comment: Technological limit? Limited to the number of ports that you can open to instantiate requests from - anything else you can change by spending more money on cpu/ram/bandwidth.  Sensible limit?  Why would you need to be connected to more than "a few" servers at any one time?

Comment: I'm thrown off by your use of the words "how many connections should be *ideally* open" and "anyone has a *good* number?" -- are you asking for limits, or normal practices?

Comment: Thanks ivanivan and jeff. I am looking for the limits and the best practices. I'll add more clarity to the question

Answer (score 0):

For each IP addresss there are 65535 ports, and each connection uses one.  Also the server port is reserved.  The system uses some ports internally, but with effort you could probably get 65530.  The technical max is about 64000, but **you will most likely run out of memory or CPU before you reach that limit.**

You could add multiple NICs(network cards) and get 64000 per NIC as each NIC has a unique IP address.

If you have 7 pci-e slots, and buy quad nic's that 7*4 or 28 network adapters *64000.

That many connection will require a lot of CPU/

Comment: You do not need multiple NICs to have multiple I addresses. You can add multiple IP addresses to a single interface.